# Sphinx documentation: define but hide heading/title text

Tags: python, python-sphinx, html-title

I'm using Sphinx to document a Python package. The top of the title page / splash page holds a graphic with a logo and text for the project. This gives the visual appearance that I want, but because I have defined no top-level heading the page `title` metadata (which renders in the browser tab) is set to `<no title> — my project name`.

Is there a way I can do one of the following?

1. Define a title text but not have it render as a heading on the page?
2. Set the `title` page metadata some other way?

Answer (score 5):

You can customize the theme, overriding the part that contains the `<title>` tag. See [Templating](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/templating.html) in the Sphinx documentation for complete information. If you have the "basic" theme, you would need to override [line 130 in layout.html](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/themes/basic/layout.html#L130)

```
    <title>{{ title|striptags|e }}{{ titlesuffix }}</title>
```

You can apply control structures in themes using [Jinja2 templating language](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#if), in case you want to apply this feature for only one page and not others.

Comment: This is a good answer but I wonder how to do it ONLY FOR ONE page (e.g. start page).