# Sphinx: how to change html title?

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I'm working on my RTFM Documentation and I d'like to change the html-title. Currently, my title looks like this:

```
<title>[PAGE TITLE] — My Documentation  documentation</title>
```

Everything the [PAGE TITLE] part as well as `- My Documentation` part is fine like it is, but I don't need the second "documentation"

In the end, it should look like this:

`<title>[PAGE TITLE] — My Documentation</title>`

Does anyone knows where I can remove it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the configuration value [`html_title`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_title). You can set it either in your `conf.py` or on the command line.

## conf.py

```
html_title = 'Beep Boop'
```

## output

```
<title>[PAGE TITLE] &#8212; Beep Boop</title>
```

Comment: Where does the `PAGE TITLE` comes from? I have a page generating a <no title> as this value. Is it the `h1` title?

Comment: Questions in comments will not be answered. Please click the "Ask Question" button in the upper right to ask your new question.

Comment: That's just a question so you can improve your answer. It would make no sense to duplicate this question to ask how to modify the whole html title (and not just part of it). I probably googled something like *change html title in sphinx* and ended up here.

Comment: Your question is not the same as the OP's.

Comment: @cglacet, you probably already know this but seeing as this question is well-ranked on search engines I'll answer it: yes, the `PAGE TITLE` comes from the first header ( `# PAGE TITLE` ) on the page.

Comment: @cglacet See [sphinx issue #8356](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/8356) for a request to override this.  Also asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45177750/sphinx-documentation-define-but-hide-heading-title-text).